# How can I replace the win 10 boot pictures?

Tags: windows-10, boot, pictures

I would like to change the pictures that appear behind the password login when I boot win 10. Where are they located and will deleting them and adding my own to that location give me the pics I want?

Comment: The following URL will help you to do this: https://www.howtogeek.com/223875/how-to-change-the-login-screen-background-on-windows-10/

Comment: THank you. I searched but could not find.

Comment: Well, that link's suggestion is to an app. Is that the only way?

Comment: The app likely makes it easier to change the files in question, since they are located deeper within the OS's file structure, and tampering with them could lead to problems.

Comment: "Well, that link's suggestion is to an app. Is that the only way?"  [Change Windows 10 login background without using external software?](https://superuser.com/questions/969369/change-windows-10-login-background-without-using-external-software) = duplicate. :)